# Olingo (OData 4): how set translation of EntitySet (Entity) names?

Tags: java, odata, olingo

I have names for EntitySet (Entity) in Latin, but want to get it in Cyrillic after mapping in view.

How can I set pseudonyms for Olingo (OData 4) EntitySet(Entity)?
Or, is it possible to use some translation mechanism in Olingo?
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic translation mechanism in Olingo.
You can either use the "title" of an EntitySet to contain the Cyrillic information if this is the only other language you want to support.
If you have multiple languages I would suggest you add EdmAnnotations to your EntitySet. In these Annotations you can have the translated value.

Comment: Thank you! How can i set 'title' of an EntitySet with CSDL and get it in client? Cool to see a snippet!

Comment: Found it: property 'title' of EntitySet is available since v. 4.1.0. And it really can be used as alternative name. It's solved. Thanx!